# Why is my geo coordinate always false?

Tags: geolocation, twitter

I'm sending a tweet to `@JoeMaxiTaxis` from my Android phone. The trouble is, the coordinates simply do not show up.

I double checked that GPS is enabled and that location is enabled on the Twitter app.

Here is the response I get on the server:

```
{ in_reply_to_status_id_str: null,
  contributors: null,
  place: null,
  in_reply_to_screen_name: 'JoeMaxiTaxis',
  text: '@joemaxitaxis lll',
  favorited: false,
  in_reply_to_user_id_str: '634579476',
  coordinates: null,
  geo: null,
  retweet_count: 0,
  created_at: 'Fri Jul 13 22:13:01 +0000 2012',
  source: '<a href="http://twitter.com/download/android" rel="nofollow">Twitter for Android</a>',
  in_reply_to_user_id: 634579476,
  in_reply_to_status_id: null,
  retweeted: false,
  id_str: '223902880527167488',
  truncated: false,
  user: 
   { favourites_count: 0,
     friends_count: 0,
     profile_background_color: 'C0DEED',
     following: null,
     profile_background_tile: false,
     profile_background_image_url_https: 'https://si0.twimg.com/images/themes/theme1/bg.png',
     followers_count: 0,
     profile_image_url: 'http://a0.twimg.com/sticky/default_profile_images/default_profile_0_normal.png',
     contributors_enabled: false,
     geo_enabled: true,
     created_at: 'Wed Jul 07 16:19:53 +0000 2010',
     profile_sidebar_fill_color: 'DDEEF6',
     description: '',
     listed_count: 0,
     follow_request_sent: null,
     time_zone: 'Dublin',
     url: null,
     verified: false,
     profile_sidebar_border_color: 'C0DEED',
     default_profile: true,
     show_all_inline_media: false,
     is_translator: false,
     notifications: null,
     profile_use_background_image: true,
     protected: false,
     profile_image_url_https: 'https://si0.twimg.com/sticky/default_profile_images/default_profile_0_normal.png',
     location: 'Dublin, Ireland',
     id_str: '163924257',
     profile_text_color: '333333',
     name: 'Eamonn Hynes',
     statuses_count: 6,
     profile_background_image_url: 'http://a0.twimg.com/images/themes/theme1/bg.png',
     id: 163924257,
     default_profile_image: true,
     lang: 'en',
     utc_offset: 0,
     profile_link_color: '0084B4',
     screen_name: 'rainbowcabs' },
  id: 223902880527167500,
  entities: { user_mentions: [ [Object] ], urls: [], hashtags: [] } }
```

Can anyone offer any insight?

Comment: figured it out... You have to press the GPS pin when composing the tweet... Doh!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does your HTTP request get the `long` and the `lat` parameters that contains your GPS coordinates (longitude and latitude) ? Whatever your app does with the GPS, if Twitter does not got both `long` and `lat` parameters and if you are not "geo enabled", Twitter will not be able to return you the location with the rest of the written tweet.